# How can I validate that if the text has such a word that it cuts and creates an array for me

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, substring

I need to get my string, which returns everything in one row and separates it by patterns.

For example, as seen in the text below, I need that if it finds the word stop, it will cut the string and return it to me in an array, then the next time it finds the word, it will cut it and so on. with the third which would be andres

Since I need to separate it into 3 arrays, I am new to javascript and maybe there is an easier way to do it than I imagine. Thank you very much I hope you can help me.

```
 var texto = "Catherine was there Sitting under a laurel Looking 
at the coolness of the falling waters Suddenly a soldier passed 
by 
and made him stop. stop soldier, I want to ask you a question 
Haven't you seen my husband who went to war one day? I haven't 
seen her husband I don't even know who (how) he is My husband is 
tall and blond, as handsome as you are. And on the tip of the hat 
it has San Andres written And on the tip of his sword is written 
San Andres"


//I need it to return me like this:
//Example:
let primerSeccion = ["Catherine was there Sitting under a laurel Looking at the coolness of the falling waters Suddenly a soldier passed by and made him stop"]
let segundaSeccion = ["I want to ask you a question Haven't you seen my husband who went to war one day? I haven't seen her husband I don't even know who (how) he is"]
let terceraSeccion = ["My husband is tall and blond, as handsome as you are. And on the tip of the hat it has San Andres written And on the tip of his sword is written San Andres"]

//What I tried was the following...
//If text includes the word stop. It should kill the execution and as far as it got it should save in an array.
let primerSeccion = [];
let segundaSeccion = [];
let terceraSeccion = [];
//I've tried various ways I've found.. But none come even close to what I need.
console.log(texto[0,6] === "Catherine")
console.log(texto.includes('stop'))
for (let index = 0; index < texto.length; index++) {
  return texto.includes("stop")
  
}
```

[image]

Comment: What criteria for separate string, is length words, based to word or newline ?

Comment: should be based on words

Comment: I didn't understand because "stop soldier" is not present in the result of your strings, What words is used for split the string  ?

Comment: there I edited the question with an image with more example

Answer (score 0):

An issue in your code on image your code present different uppercase letters, this is an idea for resolve it

```
  let primerSeccion = texto.substring( 0, texto.indexOf(" Stop"))
  let segundaSeccion = texto.substring( texto.indexOf("Stop"),  texto.indexOf(" My"))
  let terceraSeccion = texto.substring ( texto.indexOf("My"))
```

I used **`substring`** and **`indexOf`**

**substring()** extracts characters from **indexStart** up to but not including **indexEnd**. In particular:

- If **indexEnd** is omitted, **substring()** extracts characters to the end of the string.
- If **indexStart** is equal to **indexEnd**, **substring()** returns an empty string.
- If **indexStart** is greater than **indexEnd**, then the effect of **substring()** is as if the two arguments were swapped; see example below.

Any argument value that is less than **0** or greater than **str.length** is treated as if it were **0** and **str.length**, respectively.

Source : **[MDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74266750/how-can-i-validate-that-if-the-text-has-such-a-word-that-it-cuts-and-creates-an?noredirect=1#)**

**indexOf()** compares **searchElement** to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the **`===`** or triple-equals operator).

- The **indexOf()** method skips empty slots in sparse arrays.
- The **indexOf()** method is generic. It only expects the this value to
  have a length property and integer-keyed properties.

Source : [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)